# Is there a way to backfill missing rows in SQL table with a reference table?

Tags: sql, join

Let's say I have a table for 3 days (2023-01-01 to 2023-01-03) of data that looks like this

| Name | date | budget |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-01-01 | 10 |
| A | 2023-01-03 | 15 |
| B | 2023-01-02 | 12 |
| B | 2023-01-03 | 17 |

I want to calculate the average budget over 3 days, but as you can see both A and B have missing data - A misses data from 2023-01-02 and B misses data from 2023-01-01. Instead of ignoring these missing data, I want to fill in data from a reference table which might look like

| date | budget |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 12 |
| 2023-01-02 | 15 |
| 2023-01-03 | 20 |

So that I should end up with something like

| Name | date | budget |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-01-01 | 10 |
| A | 2023-01-03 | 15 |
| A | 2023-01-02 | 15 |
| B | 2023-01-02 | 12 |
| B | 2023-01-03 | 17 |
| B | 2023-01-01 | 12 |

So the 1/2 data for A and 1/1 data for B are taken from the reference table now. Is there a way to do this in SQL? Thanks!

I'm thinking of cross join but I'm not entirely sure how that would solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cross join` with a `left join`:

```
select t.name, rt.date, coalesce(t1.budget, rt.budget) from 
  (select distinct t.name from tbl t) t 
cross join ref_tbl rt left join tbl t1 on t1.name = t.name and t1.date = rt.date
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UJUT3Gv5)